# Shorthand get textContent if querySelector doesn't return null

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was try trying to find a shorthand way to do something like this

```
let text = el.querySelector('.some-class').textContent || ''
```

However the above gives an error:

> Object is possibly 'null'.

So I randomly decided to try this, and I get no errors any more. However, I don't know what it is doing or if it is doing what I want it to do.

```
let text = el.querySelector('.some-class')!.textContent || ''
```

Basically I am looking for a way to trigger the `textContent` part if an element is found otherwise trigger the part after the `||`.

I am not sure what the expression I just wrote is, so I don't really know what to Google here.

What I think it is saying is **to not evaluate the expression with a null result** like when defining a type:

```
public value!: string
```

If I am correct is there a proper way to do what I would like?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a utility function:

```ts
function getElText(query: string): string {
  const el = document.querySelector(query);
  return el && el.textContent || '';
}
```

Once [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) gets added to JS, you will likely be able to do this in TS/JS:

```
let text = el.querySelector('.some-class')?.textContent || ''
```

In your working example, the `!.` is telling TS to ignore the possible `null` type, so you can access properties on `el`, but if `querySelector` returns `null`, you will get a runtime error.

Comment: The optional chaining is very helpful, I hope it gets implemented

Comment: I agree. It just recently reached stage 2, so hopefully it won't be long.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is warning you that `el.querySelector('.some-class')` may return `null`. Essentially, if for whatever reason no element in your DOM matches that selector query (.some-class), you'll get `null` back. Then if you try to read the `.textContent` of null, that'll throw an exception. TypeScript is fore-warning you about this possibility.

To achieve the effect you desire, you can do something like:

```
let element = el.querySelector('.some-class');
let text = element ? element.textContent : "";
```

As far as why putting a `!` got rid of the error message, that's TypeScript's bang non-null-assertion operator [described here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator). With the `!` you're essentially telling TypeScript not to worry about the null possibility. It's useful when you, as the developer with knowledge of other parts of your application, can assert that a parameter won't be null.

Answer (score 0):

[Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) are part of typescript 3.7, so you can now use:

```js
let text = el.querySelector('.some-class')?.textContent ?? ''
```